# Visual Basic: is there a way to consolidate 7 click-events that call the same sub procedure?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My intention is to have calculated labels clear anytime a new radio button is selected. Currently, I'm doing that with 7 separate click-events calling the same sub procedure, like so:

```
' the following 7 subprocedures clear totals boxes if any radio button is changed
Private Sub rbCappuccino_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbCappuccino.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub

Private Sub rbChocolate_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbChocolate.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub

Private Sub rbFilled_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbFilled.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub

Private Sub rbGlazed_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbGlazed.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub

Private Sub rbNone_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbNone.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub

Private Sub rbRegular_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbRegular.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub

Private Sub rbSugar_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbSugar.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub
```

I'm curious as to whether or not there is a way to consolidate these events given they all call the exact same sub procedure. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can attach multiple events to a single event handler:

```
Private Sub CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbCappuccino.CheckedChanged, rbChocolate.CheckedChanged, rbFilled.CheckedChanged, rbGlazed.CheckedChanged, rbNone.CheckedChanged, rbRegular.CheckedChanged, rbSugar.CheckedChanged
    Call ClearLabels()
End Sub
```

Inside such code you can even detect which CheckBox called the event to act on individual controls:

```
If CType(sender, CheckBox).Text = "Cup of Java" ....
```

Comment: Very fast response - much appreciated.

Comment: SO is browsed by thousands of coders eager to answer :) usually you get pretty fast response here, it's an amazing resource.